# Generate a python parser for a particular JSON format

Tags: python, json, validation, parsing

I'm using a file format.  The format is, effectively, JSON with a particular structure.  The format comes with a validator, which is great, and gives helpful error messages.  However, the validator fails when the error causes the input to be invalid JSON, and gives a very poor error message.

I can use this with a normal JSON validator, but what I really want to do is to be able to put a JSON structure into a tool, and get a (python) parser out of the other end. Obviously there are various ways of doing this, my question is: are there any ways of defining a JSON format that let me avoid writing a parser for JSON itself?

The use case is this: I would like to build a 'proper' validator for the format, so that a user can upload their file and have it checked.  I can just write the BNF, but I'd like to write the BNF for a tool that understand it was BNF-within-JSON.

Comment: If they send you invalid JSON is there something they need to know besides that it is invalid?  Just use the normal `json.loads` to check it is valid JSON.

Comment: Do you know what JSON stands for? JavaScript Object Notation, it is already a notation, there is only *one* valid "format".

well formated JSON objects can be parsed with builtin module json

from json import loads

loads(jsonObjectAsString)

Comment: it is also hard to guess what do you want to do. Usually you would like to parse json with json module or jsonpickle and then check the validity of your data

Comment: @Alex,  JSON schema, looks a lot like the perfect answer - thank you.

Comment: @AlexHall - would you like to make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate way to assert that a JSON file follows a particular format is to use [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/). This is supported across many languages and has good libraries in Python. There's also helpful online tools to generate, validate, and test schema.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the validator uses a json library to read the file, and then makes some additional checks.. This sounds like a good design to me; why reinvent the wheel? If invalid JSON gives error messages that are too cryptic, how about catching them in a `try ... except` block and formulating the error message your own way? In addition to the exception message, you can recover quite a bit of information about the error by inspecting the exception.

If you could be more specific about what kind of error message you find unhelpful and what you would like to see instead (with suitable input that triggers the error), maybe someone can explain how.